# MySQL Query not returning newest results on setInterval

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am having a problem with **setInterval** in the **$(document).ready(function(){}**

What I am doing is setting the interval to do is call a PHP script that runs some MySQL queries to check the condition of 4 switches and then updating the screen with the values are in the database like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

setInterval(function(){

<?php require('fetchSwitchStatuses.php'); ?>

$("#switch1").css('background', 'rgb(<?php echo $switchColor1 ?>)');
$("#switch1").html('<?php echo $switchState1 ?>');
$("#switch2").css('background', 'rgb(<?php echo $switchColor2 ?>)');
$("#switch2").html('<?php echo $switchState2 ?>');
$("#switch3").css('background', 'rgb(<?php echo $switchColor3 ?>)');
$("#switch3").html('<?php echo $switchState3 ?>');
$("#switch4").css('background', 'rgb(<?php echo $switchColor4 ?>)');
$("#switch4").html('<?php echo $switchState4 ?>');
  },1000);

});
```

**Here is the code for fetchSwitchStatuses.php:**

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysqli_select_db($connect, "db_name");


$fetch1 = mysqli_query($connect,
"SELECT SwitchStatus FROM Switches WHERE PinNumber = '3'"
);
$fetch2 = mysqli_query($connect,
"SELECT SwitchStatus FROM Switches WHERE PinNumber = '5'"
);
$fetch3 = mysqli_query($connect,
"SELECT SwitchStatus FROM Switches WHERE PinNumber = '6'"
);
$fetch4 = mysqli_query($connect,
"SELECT SwitchStatus FROM Switches WHERE PinNumber = '9'"
);


$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array(${'fetch'.$i}))
{

    if($row['SwitchStatus'] == 0)
    {
        ${'switchColor'.$i} = "255, 0, 0";
        ${'switchState'.$i} = "OFF";

    }
    else if ($row['SwitchStatus'] == 1){
        ${'switchColor'.$i} = "0, 255, 0";
        ${'switchState'.$i} = "ON";
    }
    else {
        ${'switchColor'.$i} = "100, 100, 100";
        ${'switchState'.$i} = "ERROR";
    }
$i++;
}


mysqli_close($connect);
```

When the page is loaded the information is correct, whatever is in the database is what is reflected by the colors on the screen.

When I click on the object to change the value, all of the necessary changes are made and the database is updated. However, the problem arises when the Interval is repeated. The values are switched back to whatever the original values were when the page was loaded. So, although the information is correctly changed in the database, for some reason the colors of the buttons is always reset to the first value read by the queries.

How can I fix this so that the information that is reflected on the screen is accurate?

Comment: do you update `$switchColor1`,`$switchColor2` and... after database update?

Comment: Actually I dont think I have used database update anywhere... im a bit confused. So what your saying is that after the value is changed? here is an example of how one of the values is changed:
 $changeValue = mysqli_query($connect,

 "UPDATE Switches
 SET SwitchStatus=1
 WHERE PinNumber = 9"
 
 );

Comment: The question is where do you set and update `$switchColor1` and ...?

Comment: in a php file called turnOnswitch1.php or turnOffswitch1.php and the code is in my previous response

Comment: basically im trying to get the page to update and show like stack overflow when you get a new message or on facebook when you get a like or a message and the little red thing shows up...

Comment: @Amir it updates in the php....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AJAX technology you can:
Send a request and get results from server by requesting a page (a .txt .js .html or even php).
So with AJAX you can get result of a page save something to database, get something from data base, you can work with sessions and anything you can do with a php file.
When you send an AJAX request to a see a page(i.e  /userData.php?userId=5) the page /userData.php?userId=5 will be executed and its output will be returned.(HTML or just a word ‘yes’ or ‘no’ or ‘you can’t access to this user’s information’).
You can send data to file with POST or GET. But the question is how you can get data from page. Because the result AJAX will give you is what the requested page echoed to page like this

```
<html>
….
</html>
```

Or

```
‘Yes’
```

Or

```
<?php echo ‘something’; ?>
```

So what about getting a row of Date or lots of data? Because the only thing you are getting is a text or maybe a long text.
For that you can use JSON which Is something like nested arrays.

```
[ 
{ 
"term": "BACCHUS", 
"part": "n.", 
"definition": "A convenient deity invented by the...", 
"quote": [ 
"Is public worship, then, a sin,", 
"That for devotions paid to Bacchus", 
"The lictors dare to run us in,", 
"And resolutely thump and whack us?" 
], 
"author": "Jorace" 
},
…
```

And this is a string too. But you can get Data in it with $.getJSON in jQuery and you can generate JSON data in server side like this.

```
<?php
$arr=array(
‘data’=>’ffff’,
‘anotherData’=>array(‘rrrrr’,’sssss’);
);
Echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Json_encode() in PHP gets an array and returns json string of it. And we echo it.
Now we can use jQuery to get Data which will be retrieved from server.
This section if from
 **Learning jQuery 1.3

Better Interaction Design and Web Development with Simple
 JavaScript Techniques

Jonathan Chaffer

Karl Swedberg**


Global jQuery functions
To this point, all jQuery methods that we've used have been attached to a jQuery object that we've built with the $() factory function. The selectors have allowed us to specify a set of DOM nodes to work with, and the methods have operated on them in some way. This $.getJSON() function, however, is different. There is no logical DOM element to which it could apply; the resulting object has to be provided to the script, not injected into the page. For this reason, getJSON() is defined as a method of the global jQuery object (a single object called jQuery or $ defined once by the jQuery library), rather than of an individual jQuery object instance (the objects we create with the $() function). 
If JavaScript had classes like other object-oriented languages, we'd call $.getJSON() a class method. For our purposes, we'll refer to this type of method as a global function; in effect, they are functions that use the jQuery namespace so as not to conflict with other function names.
To use this function, we pass it the file name as before:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#letter-b a').click(function() { 
$.getJSON('b.json'); 
return false; 
});
});
```

This code has no apparent effect when we click the link. The function call loads the file, but we have not told JavaScript what to do with the resulting data. For this, we need to use a callback function.
The $.getJSON() function takes a second argument, which is a function to be called when the load is complete. As mentioned before, AJAX calls are asynchronous, and the callback provides a way to wait for the data to be transmitted rather than executing code right away. The callback function also takes an argument, which is filled with the resulting data. So, we can write:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#letter-b a').click(function() { 
$.getJSON('b.json', function(data) { 
}); 
return false; 
});
});
```

Here we are using an anonymous function as our callback, as has been common in our jQuery code for brevity. A named function could equally be provided as the callback.
Inside this function, we can use the data variable to traverse the data structure as necessary. We'll need to iterate over the top-level array, building the HTML for each item. We could do this with a standard for loop, but instead we'll introduce another of jQuery's useful global functions, $.each(). We saw its counterpart, the .each() method, in Chapter 5. Instead of operating on a jQuery object, this function takes an array or map as its first parameter and a callback function as its second. Each time through the loop, the current iteration index and the current item in the array or map are passed as two parameters to the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#letter-b a').click(function() { 
$.getJSON('b.json', function(data) { 
$('#dictionary').empty(); 
$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) { 
var html = '<div class="entry">'; 
html += '<h3 class="term">' + entry['term'] + '</h3>'; 
html += '<div class="part">' + entry['part'] + '</div>'; 
html += '<div class="definition">'; 
html += entry['definition']; 
html += '</div>'; 
html += '</div>'; 
$('#dictionary').append(html); 
}); 
}); 
return false; 
});
});
```

Before the loop, we empty out  so that we can fill it with our newly-constructed HTML. Then we use $.each() to examine each item in turn, building an HTML structure using the contents of the entry map. Finally, we turn this HTML into a DOM tree by appending it to the .

This approach presumes that the data is safe for HTML consumption; it should not contain any stray < characters, for example.

Comment: holy cow, thanks man this is great! Im going to read through this now (im about half way through already!) I really appreciate the time you have taken to help me =D

Comment: Do you recommend using this method or using websockets?

Comment: your welcome man. you can give some love back with supporting me.(vote my answer and comments and accept my answer if you think its correct and useful)

Comment: but websockets is not realy needed.its for realtime games,and a developed and advanced chat maybe but not for simple requests. check this. [about websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)